# How to order an object of type "structure" based on names(c)?

Tags: r

I have an object that looks like this:

```
structure(c(0, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0), .Names = c("6", "1", "3", "4", "2", "5" ))
```

I need the values of this object  to be in the order indicated by the names, if they would be integers and not characters as they are now. The object should be (2, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0) i don't mind it to be a vector or a matrix with row names but I simply couldn't order this object.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a named vector. Function `structure` is a convenient way of packing your objects for distribution. Notice that you're missing a comma before `.Names`.

```
x <- structure(c(0, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0), .Names = c("6", "1", "3", "4", "2", "5" ))
right.order <- order(as.numeric(names(x)))
x[right.order]

1 2 3 4 5 6 
2 5 0 3 0 0
```